# How to do mongo group on Meteor server side

Tags: mongodb, meteor

On `meteor mongo` shell I can use db.collection.group but from Meteor.methods I can'd because Meteor don't support it.

How could I write a method which would do something similar to:

```js
db.orders.group({
  keyf: function(doc) {return {year:doc.createdAt.toISOString().substring(0, 4)}},
  initial: {months:{}},
  reduce: function(order, result) {
    var month = order.createdAt.getMonth()+1,
        date = order.createdAt.getDate();

    month = result.months[month] || (result.months[month] = {});
    date = month[date] || (month[date] = []);
    date.push(order);
  },
  cond: {$and: [{createdAt: {$gt: new Date("2015-01-01")}, createdAt: {$lt: new Date("2015-12-31")}}]}
})
```

Expecting result is array of objects groups by month and then grouped by dates inside months.

P.S. `orders`, is quite big collection and I really want to do grouping in the database.

---

After information about rawCollection() in 1.0.4 I tried this:

```
  collection = Orders.rawCollection();
  params = {
    keyf: function(doc) {return {year:doc.createdAt.toISOString().substring(0, 4)}},
    initial: {months:{}},
    reduce: function(order, result) {
      var month = order.createdAt.getMonth()+1,
          date = order.createdAt.getDate();

      month = result.months[month] || (result.months[month] = {});
      date = month[date] || (month[date] = []);
      date.push(order);
    },
    cond: {$and: [{createdAt: {$gt: new Date("2015-01-01")}, createdAt: {$lt: new Date("2015-12-31")}}]}
  };
  Meteor.wrapAsync(collection.group, collection)(params);
```

I'm getting:

```
W20150327-13:26:24.924(2)? (STDERR) /Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
W20150327-13:26:24.924(2)? (STDERR)         throw message;      
W20150327-13:26:24.924(2)? (STDERR)               ^
W20150327-13:26:24.929(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150327-13:26:24.929(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/aggregation.js:229:22
W20150327-13:26:24.931(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1191:22
W20150327-13:26:24.931(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
W20150327-13:26:24.931(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Base._callHandler (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
W20150327-13:26:24.932(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1758:29
W20150327-13:26:24.932(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Connection.write (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:272:16)
W20150327-13:26:24.932(2)? (STDERR)     at __executeQueryCommand (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1752:16)
W20150327-13:26:24.932(2)? (STDERR)     at Db._executeQueryCommand (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1902:7)
W20150327-13:26:24.933(2)? (STDERR)     at Db.command (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1183:8)
W20150327-13:26:24.933(2)? (STDERR)     at Collection.group (/Users/jaro/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.1jqg8g6++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/aggregation.js:228:13)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Meteor v1.0.4:

> Provide direct access to the collection and database objects from the npm Mongo driver via new `rawCollection` and `rawDatabase` methods on `Mongo.Collection`

So you can call `collection.rawCollection()` to get the underlying collection object:

```js
var rawCollection = Orders.rawCollection();
```

This `rawCollection` has a method `group` which is equivalent to the `group` method in the MongoDB shell. The underlying node API is asynchronous, though, so you'll want to convert it to a synchronous function somehow. We can't use `Meteor.wrapAsync` directly since `group` takes function arguments that aren't the primary callback, so we'll work around this with a wrapper:

```js
function ordersGroup(/* arguments */) {
    var args = _.toArray(arguments);
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(function (callback) {
        rawCollection.group.apply(rawCollection, args.concat([callback]));
    })();
}
```

Inside your method, you can call `ordersGroup` like you would `db.orders.group` in the Mongo shell. However, the arguments are passed separately, rather than in an object:

```js
ordersGroup(keys, condition, initial, reduce[, finalize[, command[, options]]])
```

For more information, see [this documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#group) (although note that the `callback` parameter should be left out, as our async-wrapping takes care of that).

So you'll have to pass them in separately:

```js
var result = ordersGroup(
    // keys
    function(doc) {
        return { year: doc.createdAt.toISOString().substring(0, 4) };
    },

    // condition
    {createdAt: {$lt: new Date("2015-12-31"), $gt: new Date("2015-01-01")}},

    // initial
    {months: {}},

    // reduce
    function(order, result) {
        var month = order.createdAt.getMonth()+1,
            date = order.createdAt.getDate();

        month = result.months[month] || (result.months[month] = {});
        date = month[date] || (month[date] = []);
        date.push(order);
    }
);
```

Of course, this only works on the server, so make sure your method is in server-only code (preferably in the `server` subdirectory, or inside an `if (Meteor.isServer)`).

Comment: I tried to use rawCollection() but still doesn't work. Not sure if I'm using it properly. Any ideas what I did wrong? (see update in my question)

Comment: You're using `wrapAsync` incorrectly, try `Meteor.wrapAsync(collection.group, collection)(params)`

Comment: thanks from correction, but unfortunately I still getting error. (I have just updated my question).

Comment: I found the problem, the `group` method in the node driver is different from in the shell for some reason. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14415578/3374348), I'll update my answer.