# How to sort in a specific order of a key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

Good day. I have the following documents.

```
{
  id: 1,
  status: "sleeping"
}
{
  id: 2,
  status: "eating"
},
{
  id: 3,
  status: "drinking"
},
{
  id: 4,
  status: "drinking"
},
{
  id: 5,
  status: "sleeping"
},
{
  id: 6,
  status: "studying"
},
...
```

How do I sort them by status with the following order? **sleeping**, **drinking**, **eating**, **studying**

I'm using Angular-Meteor. And I'm trying to **publish** a collection with a **limit** in the server since I'm dealing with a very large data set.

I was looking into **aggregate** which I think is the right solution for this case but Meteor doesn't support it.

Comment: you are looking to group them instead of sort them

Comment: Can I ask for an example?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongodb aggregation framework *is* available on the server side via the [monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation](https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation) package (for example). You can use this in your publication.

Another approach is to denormalize your data somewhat and include the sort key in each document. That involves a typical storage vs. speed tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up including sort keys for my documents.

Comment: Adding an artificial sort key should be beneficial for what reason exactly? The key is present, and the order is known. Imho, even grouping is not really necessary and this use case can be fulfilled 4 async limited requests for each of the keys.

Comment: One could run a benchmark to see whether aggregation or the extra sort key were faster, as a function of the size of the data set. He wants to sort and limit, then publish, presumably reactively.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up with attaching a number to sort the the documents in the following order: **sleeping**, **drinking**, **eating**, **studying**

```
{
  id: 1,
  status: "sleeping",
  statusOrder: 0
}
{
  id: 2,
  status: "eating",
  statusOrder: 2
},
{
  id: 3,
  status: "drinking",
  statusOrder: 1
},
{
  id: 4,
  status: "drinking",
  statusOrder: 1
},
{
  id: 5,
  status: "sleeping",
  statusOrder: 0
},
{
  id: 6,
  status: "studying",
  statusOrder: 3
},
...
```

It was easier, quite frankly.

But if you are interested with using MongoDB group for your app, I found something that might help. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295143/how-to-do-mongo-group-on-meteor-server-side).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb just only support sort following A -> Z, Z -> A, 0 -> 9, 9 -> 0

Specify in the sort parameter the field or fields to sort by and a value of 1 or -1 to specify an ascending or descending sort respectively.

Example:
db.orders.find().sort( { "status": -1 } )

Comment: Ahhh. That's too bad. But is there any other way than using sort? I'm currently looking into aggregation but I don't think that's it either.

Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: It may be help you for aggregation
http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-and-group-example/

Comment: Thanks. I also found something that's close to what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192098/mongo-how-to-sort-by-external-weight. Unfortunately, I'm using Angular-Meteor and it doesn't support reactive aggregation which my app needs.